# How to resize the inserted picture from excel to outlook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word, office-automation

this is the code I am trying, I wanna resize the inserted picture in outlook. I tried differet methods but its not working. Could anyone tell which picture object/function or method I can use to adjust the width and height of the picture?

Sub SendOutlookMail()

```
Dim outlookApplication As Outlook.Application
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim msgText As String
Dim sp As Double

Set outlookApplication = New Outlook.Application

Set mail = outlookApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With mail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "Report " & Date
        Set insp = .GetInspector
        Set doc = insp.WordEditor
        msgText = "Hallo " & vbNewLine
        doc.Range.InsertBefore msgText
                   
        Tabelle2.Range("A1:I32").Copy
        doc.Range(Len(msgText), Len(msgText)).PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        
    End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code found on the internet which resize the images, but it applies to the entire document, you can get the pasted image and replace the  `For Each oShp In ActiveDocument.Shapes` part in the code:

```
Sub AllPictSize()
    Dim targetHeight As Integer
    Dim oShp As shape
    Dim oILShp As InlineShape
    targetHeight = 9
    For Each oShp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
      With oShp
        .Width = AspectHt(.Height, .Width, _
         CentimetersToPoints(9))
        .Height = CentimetersToPoints(9)
      End With
    Next

    For Each oILShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
      With oILShp
          .Width = AspectHt(.Height, .Width, _
          CentimetersToPoints(9))
          .Height = CentimetersToPoints(9)
      End With
    Next

End Sub

Private Function AspectHt(ByVal origWd As Long, ByVal origHt As Long, ByVal newWd As Long) As Long
    If origWd <> 0 Then
        AspectHt = (CSng(origHt) / CSng(origWd)) * newWd
    Else
        AspectHt = 0
    End If
End Function
```